# How I'll convert "ı" character to "I" which is within a word with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

Like aıdK -> aIdK

Note: http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U0131/Latin_Small_Letter_Dotless_I

Comment: Can the 'ı' be at the beginning or end of the word, or does it have to be flanked on both sides by another letter?

Comment: You mean like the equivalent of Perl’s `s/\B(ı)\B/\u$1/g`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var mystring = "aıdK";

newstring = mystring.replace("ı","l"); //aldK

Comment: As long as the JavaScript itself is fetched as UTF-8/16 (well, Unicode) this should work fine. However, it is possible to imagine an incompatible encoding due to server configuration.

Answer (score 5):

```
var convertedString = string.replace(/\u0131/g,'I');
```